# Cannot save model in TensorFlow PERMISSION_DENIED

Tags: python, tensorflow, model, permission-denied

```
Below is the location that I save,
# Checkpoint location:
checkpoint_dir = './training_checkpoints'
checkpoint_prefix = os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, "my_ckpt")

**#Saiving the weight:**
model.save_weights(checkpoint_prefix)

and below is the error msg,
```

W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1839] OP_REQUIRES failed at save_restore_v2_ops.cc:292 :       PERMISSION_DENIED: ./training_checkpoints/my_ckpt_temp/part-00000-of-00001.data-00000-of-00001; Permission denied

```
I tried in both Windows and WSL2(Ubuntu 22.04).
```